# Is complete boost going to be included in C++0x?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Many utilities of boost have been included as part of [extended C++ TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Technical_Report_1) currently.

Is the complete **boost** library going to be included once the standard is officially out ? In other words, do I need boost library, if I have complete standard conforming C++11 compiler ?

If not then any reason for that (Reliability cannot be an issue; as far as I know it's written by many people from standard committee) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Boost is huge, and of generally high but still varying quality.  A lot of the APIs - even the techniques and functionality - are quite "experimental" in the sense that they're still regularly modified as real-world feedback comes in.  By way of contrast, the Standard is expected to get it right and need minimal revision, especially when that breaks backwards compatibility.

  - The standard for review for Standard libraries is much higher than boost's, which is not to say that many boost libraries wouldn't meet the bar - just that many wouldn't too, and that the review process itself is time consuming.  There are terrific programmers coordinating and contributing to boost, but they naturally focus their time on their own development interests and things they see as more relevant, so if something is a little specialised, doesn't appeal to their coding style, etc. it may not receive the same scrutiny.  The Standard library needs to be scrutinised much more thoroughly as the consequences of change are so much more painful.
- While portability is a factor in acceptance of a library into boost, it's not a hard and fast requirement, where-as compiler vendors are expected to make the Standard library run on all C++ compilers, so taking boost more or less as-is and expecting the functionality to be universal on Standard-compliant compiler vendors would put a huge workload on those vendors.

Answer (score 8):

No, in fact very few parts of Boost are "included" in the C++0x revisions to the C++ Standard Library.  The parts that are "included" are some of the most commonly used parts of Boost, though.

Really, "included" isn't correct anyway:  there are many differences between the Boost libraries and the corresponding additions to the C++ Standard Library.  Further, the Boost libraries continue to grow and evolve; the C++0x Standard Library is now finished.

Answer (score 3):

No, Boost is not going to be included in its entirety in C++0x.

Parts of Boost will be, like boost::shared_ptr, Boost.Array, and a couple of other things. But most of Boost is not being included.

Comment: If you have a reference to a list of which parts of Boost are included in the standard, you should post it.